# Jooq batchInsert().execute()

Tags: configuration, jooq

My process looks like:

1. select some data 50 rows per select,
2. do sth with data (set some values)
3. transform row to object of another table
4. call batchInsert(myListOfRecords).execute()

My problem is how to set up when data should be inserted ? In my current setup data is only inserted at the end of my loop. This is some kind of problem for me because i want process much more data then i do in my tests. So if i will agree with this then my proccess will end with exception (OutOfMemory). Where i should define max amount of data in batch to call instert?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is to not fetch all the rows you want to process into memory in one go. When using jOOQ, this is done using [`ResultQuery.fetchLazy()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--) (possibly along with [`ResultQuery.fetchSize(int)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize-int-)). You can then fetch the next 50 rows using [`Cursor.fetchNext(50)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html#fetchNext-int-) and proceed with your insertion as follows:

```java
try (Cursor<?> cursor = ctx
   .select(...)
   .from(...)
   .fetchSize(50)
   .fetchLazy()) {

    Result<?> batch;

    for (;;) {
        batch = cursor.fetchNext(50);

        if (batch.isEmpty())
            break;

        // Do your stuff here

        // Do your insertion here
        ctx.batchInsert(...);
    }
}
```